# Angular: Display file names of uploaded files in HTML

Tags: html, angular, api, http, post

I have created an application that submits a post request to upload files into an API.

Service file:

```
onFileSelected(event){
    this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0];
  }

onUpload() {
    const formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append('uploadfile', this.selectedFile);
    return this.http
      .post('http://localhost:8080/api/file/upload/CD999/2021', formdata, {
        responseType: 'text'
      })
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
      })
        
    }
```

HTML:

```
<input type="file" (change)="onFileSelected($event)">
<button type="button" (click)="onUpload()">Upload</button>
```

I want to create a list that displays the information of uploaded files after uploading, such as name, something like this:

```
<div class="file-list" *ngFor="let file of files; let i=index">
    {{file.name}}
</div>

How can I push file information in an array to display in HTML? I have tried some things but am getting errors (having difficulty pushing objects to an array).
Or is there perhaps a better way of achieving this?

Thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
public documentList: any[] = [];

onFileSelected(event){
   this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0];
   this.documentList = event.target.files;
}

<!--HTML-->

<div *ngFor="let document of documentList; let i = index">
   {{document.name}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over `event.target.files` and push them into array.

```js
files: any[] = [];

onFileSelected(event) {

    // Iterate over selected files
    for (let file of event.target.files) {
        
        // Append to a list
        this.files.push({
            name: file.name,
            type: file.type
        });
    }
}
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-oyb1ru?file=src/app/app.component.ts